# Datamapper ORM: get an object by array of ID's

Tags: codeigniter, orm, datamapper

i have an array like this:

```
$arr = (1, 3, 87, 200);
```

I wanna get the Object for these IDs only

ca I do it like this:

```
$object = new Object($arr);

foreach($object as $o)
{
$o->user->get()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`where_in`](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/get.html#where_in) method.

```
$arr = array(1, 3, 87, 200);

$o = new Object();
$o->where_in('id', $arr);
$o->get();

// When $o->get() is called, all records where
// the id is 1, 3, 87 or 200 will be returned
```

If you wanted to order them you could use the following, before calling `get()`.

```
$o->order_by("column_1", "column_2");
```

For more bits you can do prior to get, see the manual page

http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/get.html

Comment: THANK YOU.
I have 1 more question. it works now. but objects are ordered by id, and not by the $arr.
how could I now order objects by the array ?